# Clickable labels on JSliders

Tags: label, mouselistener, clickable, jslider

I have a JSlider and I am setting JLabels (that display an icon) as the labels on the JSlider. The JLabels just display an icon. I have a MouseListener attached to the JLabel to listen to the Mouse Click event on the JLabel. However the listener never gets called. I have read about setting the Z-order etc but I am not sure how to set that on the labels of a JSlider. I am trying to make the slider move to the exact location of the label when user clicks on the label. I do not want to display any ticks.

```
slider = new JSlider(0, 1000, 0);
Hashtable< Integer, JLabel > markers = new Hashtable< Integer, JLabel >();
MyMarker mark300 = new MyMarker(300);
mark300.addMouseListener(MyListener);
MyMarker mark575 = new MyMarker(575);
mark575.addMouseListener(MyListener);
MyMarker mark820 = new MyMarker(820);
mark820.addMouseListener(MyListener);
markers.put(300, mark300);
markers.put(550, mark575);
markers.put(820, mark820);
slider.setLabelTable(markers);
```

Mouse Clicked Event never reaches MyListener. It appears that the slider captures all the events.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you have tried. A jsfiddle would be best. It's hard to help you if we don't have something to use as an example.

Comment: added code example of what I am doing.